# How to use JDBC connection from host to a docker mysql server

Tags: java, mysql, docker, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I am new in docker and I try to connect to a mysql container from the local machine (host).

I pulled the latest version of mysql with:

```
docker pull mysql/mysql-server:latest
```

and started this (and the myadmin container with the following:

```
docker run --name mysql1 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mysql --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password -P 3306 -h localhost
docker run --name myadmin -d --link mysql1:db -p 8081:80 phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
```

I can access the phpmyadmin on my local browser (with localhost:8081) and I created a DB named 'userDB'.

Here you can see the docker check:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                            NAMES
03126272c0e3        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   "/run.sh supervisord…"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        9000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8081->80/tcp   myadmin
c8d032921d7c        mysql                   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes        3306/tcp, 33060/tcp              mysql1
```

On my local JavaEE application (running on an GlassFish Webserver) I try to connect this mysql database with the following commands:

```
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userDB", "root", "root");
        return con;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Database.getConnection() Error -->"
                + ex.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
```

and got the following exception:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

What mistake do I do? How can i connect my Java application with the mysql docker container?

Comment: The app server is running on the host and not in Docker?  Does changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` help?  (It wouldn't in most cases, but MySQL in particular interprets `localhost` as meaning "use a local socket" and not "make a TCP connection to this host name".)

Comment: @DavidMaze I also tried it with the IP but it also does not work :( And you are right. The App is running on the host and not in Docker. But mysql and phpmyadmin is running fine in docker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem was that the port mapping must be one of the first parameters in the run statement of docker. This is the final run statement:

```sh
docker run -p 3306:3306 --name mysql1 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mysql --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password -h 127.0.0.1
```

The next problem was to update the JDBC driver in maven (to the newest).

And last but not least: The useSSL param was set to false (not necessary on the local machine).

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup Docker networking for that stuff to to work together. I don't review `docker-compose` here, you can do it on your own, but if using generic `docker` CLI, it will look like following:

First you create user-defined bridge network

```
docker network create foo
```

Then you start your containers attached to this net

```
docker run --network=foo --name mysql1 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mysql --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password -P 3306 -h "0.0.0.0"
docker run --network=foo --name myadmin -p 8081:80 phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
```

Notice: I changed `localhost` to `0.0.0.0` to allow remote connections and removed `link` argument - it is oboslete.

Now to connect **between services** you use their names and generic ports, like `mysql1:3306` and `myadmin:80`.

To connect to services **from host** you use `localhost` and **exposed ports**: `localhost:1234` and `localhost:8081` appropriately.

Comment: When I use this I got at the start (of the first command) the following error: `Enter password: mysqld: Can not perform keyring migration : Invalid --keyring-migration-source option.`

Comment: I've just **reduced** the command line for better visibility, now returned full version