# How to make connection with MySQL database which is running in docker using JDBC?

Tags: mysql, docker, jdbc, mysql-connector, java-17

Getting the below exception while making connection with MySQL in docker via JDBC.

The MySQL is mapped into the docker. The port informations are showing like this in the docker process list under the PORTS category
`0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, :::3306->3306/tcp`.

This is the sample code I'm using it for making connection to the database and write data into it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/sampledb", "root", "");
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("insert into demo values(1, \"A\")");
            /*Perform some operations*/
            resultSet.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The Exception trace:

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:449)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:242)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
    at Sample/com.test.Test.main(Test.java:14)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1719)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1518)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1425)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:489)
    ... 18 more
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Where are you trying to connect from? From your host? Does the Docker container map a MySQL port from the container to the host (for example `--publish 3306:3306`)? What code are you using to connect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use JDBC connection from host to a docker mysql server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54323551/12567365)? Or [any of these](https://www.google.com/search?q=docker+mysql+connect+jdbc+site:stackoverflow.com)?

Comment: @andrewJames I'm trying to connect mysql from my simple test program. I'm new to docker, based on the process list I think the MySQL is mapped into the container. The port informations are showing like this in the docker process list under the PORTS category
```0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, :::3306->3306/tcp```

Comment: @andrewJames This is the sample code I'm using

```try {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
      try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/sampledb", "root", "");
           Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
           ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("insert into demo values(1, \"A\")");
           /*Perform some operations*/
           resultSet.close();
           }
    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}```

Comment: Please update the question, instead of writing comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the docker image with the following command:

```
docker run -it -p 33060:3306 --name hakky54-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='secret' mysql
```

Get the certificate of mysql. In my case it was the snipper pem file below, but it can be different for your mysql instance.

```
subject=CN=MySQL_Server_8.3.0_Auto_Generated_Server_Certificate
issuer=CN=MySQL_Server_8.3.0_Auto_Generated_CA_Certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN=MySQL_Server_8.3.0_Auto_Generated_CA_Certificate
issuer=CN=MySQL_Server_8.3.0_Auto_Generated_CA_Certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDBDCCAeygAwIBAgIBATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADA7MTkwNwYDVQQDDDBNeVNR
TF9TZXJ2ZXJfOC4zLjBfQXV0b19HZW5lcmF0ZWRfQ0FfQ2VydGlmaWNhdGUwHhcN
MjQwMjIzMTUxMzA4WhcNMzQwMjIwMTUxMzA4WjA7MTkwNwYDVQQDDDBNeVNRTF9T
ZXJ2ZXJfOC4zLjBfQXV0b19HZW5lcmF0ZWRfQ0FfQ2VydGlmaWNhdGUwggEiMA0G
CSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQCR4QNDsdTiCrTCoShlJDiPi5DlgDjv
9d19hbGnaJUECHaREjjN6nOuGEAnWu0SN0ILiRZksvelBM5M0lggsprJZiOn/5YI
ogCMYA8QYcfTmzh28V71wWtpU1YRDC8dHuEpp+U3QiM38qV23gfYapXA8hzriDnW
f7YE0tBT8yJSpC++C5GpTzoBtQarH0TPGUWCLxMF2Rf+vE9bN3Z9M6+yXirzuoe9
PkrSDciHdgYPpd8pPRTfRgsduuFLytAGNSJGbh8pHM8HsMkvk61kacRkQZnAkC7Z
62fTeZ/eBwKlJSiAFWhWvDKwhI4HO67zd7fSk0V/Jy/pwNTs2uz4cAI9AgMBAAGj
EzARMA8GA1UdEwEB/wQFMAMBAf8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAAR9de5UkxKP
ae2+BBRbhRSQ6awjCk8R22HZv1aYdUaTcci9Ky4pQL+VgtzXNzTgDpNloLEHK7FR
+DHEHsO82uPwc7CC5lzHtCGrsYOb51gah3EnzLnG6pKvd7XwAYQStuxdCvlsSuFf
oACirqbNEhZT4Q6BaTzeH3X9pcptMb0CwAYcG1Rhebrl89TCocyQSUCKmJzuTEy5
NYM+cGD6p3KXkiKzWssYd/fq7V9/4ah9Oxex4x80fnHF5gUY3xRUywyb+ZcR32z3
UZddf1C6Kup943AjsU6NEYXWGrCNAThmuhVnBgTWOjVshbV7rOeQtc8Ou1C5MC4k
NWQTpFABwX8=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I created a truststore out of it with [KeyStore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/). The actual java code looks like this:

```java
import java.security.Security;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/path/to/truststore.p12");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:33060/mysql?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true";
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "secret")) {
            System.out.println("Database connected!");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot connect the database!", e);
        }
    }

}
```